# Find bundles of repeating values and perform operations on them separately

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have pandas Series of the type

```
    a = pd.Series([1,  4,3,5,  7,5,  5,6,7,6,  7,  6,2,2,  6,  9])
```

and a numpy array of the type

```
    b = np.array([0,  1,1,1,  0,0,  1,1,1,1,  0,  1,1,1,  0,  1])
```

Now I want to seperately generate averages of elements in `a` whenever there is a cluster of `1`'s in the corresponding parts of `b`, with the result

```
    c = pd.Series([1,  4,4,4,  7,5,  6,6,6,6,  7,  3.3,3.3,3.3  6,  9])
```

Does someone have an idea how to do this nicely?

Comment: this won't work, since it will give the average for all ones and all zeroes

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it doesn't work (just tried it).

Comment: the average of `[6,2,2]` should be `[3.3]`,if I am not missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `shift+cumsum` , note avg of `6,2,2,` is `3.333..` not 5

```
s = pd.Series(b,index=a.index)
a.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).transform('mean').where(s.eq(1),a)
```

---

```
0     1.000000
1     4.000000
2     4.000000
3     4.000000
4     7.000000
5     5.000000
6     6.000000
7     6.000000
8     6.000000
9     6.000000
10    7.000000
11    3.333333
12    3.333333
13    3.333333
14    6.000000
15    9.000000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

**Approach #1**

Here's one NumPy way -

```
In [23]: ids = np.r_[0,b[:-1]!=b[1:]].cumsum()

In [24]: np.where(b==1,a.groupby(ids).transform('mean'),a)
Out[24]: 
array([1.        , 4.        , 4.        , 4.        , 7.        ,
       5.        , 6.        , 6.        , 6.        , 6.        ,
       7.        , 3.33333333, 3.33333333, 3.33333333, 6.        ,
       9.        ])
```

**Approach #2**

For performance, we can leverage [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
In [47]: v = np.bincount(ids,a)/np.bincount(ids)

In [48]: np.where(b==1,v[ids],a)
Out[48]: 
array([1.        , 4.        , 4.        , 4.        , 7.        ,
       5.        , 6.        , 6.        , 6.        , 6.        ,
       7.        , 3.33333333, 3.33333333, 3.33333333, 6.        ,
       9.        ])
```